# gstreamer h.264 video decoding C++

Tags: c++, streaming, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264

I'm new to video decoding and to gstreamer.
I'm following their tutorial and I'd like to decode an h.264 stream.

This is the simple "HelloWorld"

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin2 uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

I'd like to play this stream:
http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4

So I modified the get_parse_launch pointing that uri but I can see only 3 white drops and then I get "out of memory".
What am I doing wrong? How can I display h264 stream?

This is the compiling instruction
gcc helloWorld.c -o helloWorld `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10`

And I can run the tutorial, so the SDK is well installed.
Anyoune can point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: How can I display h264 streaming with gstreamer in c++?

Comment: Your example seems perfectly fine. Are you getting an error? Is the display not showing up? I'd improve the example by printing the resulting message in case it is a GST_MESSAGE_ERROR, you can use gst_message_parse_error for that. Or simply run you app with GST_DEBUG=2 ./myapp

Comment: The example is ok but If I try to stream an mp4 I can only see 3 white drops on a black background and the error I see on the console is "Out of memory"